# Show columns every four records

Tags: reactjs, bulma

I'm struggling how to show columns or break columns every four records. I'm using bulma columns and my goal is to show columns on every four records inside the array map. Thanks for help.

**Inside the map function**

```
{list.map(function(item, key){
return <div className="columns">
    <div className="column">{item.name}</div>
</div>
})}
```

**Assuming the list is 8 records, the expected result should like this**

```
<div className="columns">
   <div className="column">name 1</div>
   <div className="column">name 2</div>
   <div className="column">name 3</div>
   <div className="column">name 4</div>
</div>
<div className="columns">
  <div className="column">name 5</div>
  <div className="column">name 6</div>
  <div className="column">name 7</div>
  <div className="column">name 8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does each <div className="column">1</div> contains data from specific item or?

Comment: Yes. Notice the expected result the 1-8 that might a sample only for 8 records. Every column is unique came from total 8 records.

Comment: I am working on a version which you don't hardcode 4 records, also you may have 6 records, chunks being unequal

Comment: Sorry. I'm also notice that might confusing maybe.

Comment: Yes. even if 6 records should break the 2 column. The primary goal is if the records render 4 columns then it should break the remaining column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create chunks from your array and then wrap each chunk with `<div className="columns">`

```
function array_chunks(array, chunks) {
  let result = [];
  let n = array.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i += chunks) {
    result = [...result, array.slice(i, i + chunks)];
  }
  return result;
}

let columns = array_chunks(list, 4);


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {columns.map(function(items, key) {
        return (
          <div className="columns">
            {items.map(function(item) {
              return <div className="column">{item.name}</div>;
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please see [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-mccarthy-m5q7p).

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this before rendering the columns,

```
let columns = [];
let records = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
const recordsPerColumn = 4
while (records.length) {
   columns.push(records.splice(0, recordsPerColumn));
}
// this will group the records in size of 4, which then you can iterate over 

return (
    ....
        {columns.map(function(column, key){
            return <div className="columns">
                { // for rendering the items dynamically, this will also hold good in case there are less than 4 records for say the last group
                    column.map(item=> <div className="column">{item}</div>)
                }

            </div>
        })}
    ....


)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late to the party. But here is a more precise solution:

You can use `Array.reduce` here.

```
const columns = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

{
  columns
    .reduce((acc, curr, index, self) => {
      if (index % 4 === 0) acc.push(self.slice(index, index + 4));
      return acc;
    }, [])
    .map((items, _idx) => (
      <div className="columns" key={_idx}>
        {
          items.map(item => (
            <div className="column" key={item}>{item}</div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    ))
}
```

Comment: item is not defined

Comment: @Rye sorry, didn't tested the code before posting. I have updated my answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

For the achieving the same layout, you can use the [sizing property of Bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/sizes/) columns:

```
return (
  <div className="columns">
    {list.map(function(item, key) {
      return (
        // Orders 4 items per column, rest of items rearrange automatically
        <div className="column is-one-quarter">{item.name}</div>
      )
    }}
  </div>
)}
```

If you need the specified data structure (for some other reason), then you would have to transform the data to specific data structure.

```js
function chunk (arr, len) {

  var chunks = [],
      i = 0,
      n = arr.length;

  while (i < n) {
    chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i += len));
  }

  return chunks;
}

const dummyArray = new Array(20).fill(1);

const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setData(chunk(dummyArray, 4));
  }, []);
  return (
    <main>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <div className="columns" key={index}>
          {item.map((subitem, index)=> (
            <div className="column" key={index}>
             <p>1</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </main>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.css">

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it essential that you have the 4 items split in different `div` containers?

Bulma has a `.is-multiline` class that goes on the `.columns` container that lets you add as many columns as you want and they will wrap allowing you to create a grid of items in 4 columns each.

https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/options/#multiline

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="columns is-multiline is-mobile">
<div class="column is-3">1</div>
<div class="column is-3">2</div>
<div class="column is-3">3</div>
<div class="column is-3">4</div>
<div class="column is-3">5</div>
<div class="column is-3">6</div>
<div class="column is-3">7</div>
<div class="column is-3">8</div>
</div>
```

So perhaps edit your code as such:

```
{list.map(function(item, key){
return <div className="columns is-multiline">
    <div className="column is-3">{item.name}</div>
</div>
})}
```